# Is there a way to pass parameters when visiting a page using "cy.visit" like when using "navCtrl.push('testpage', params)"?

Tags: ionic3, cypress

In my Ionic3 aplication, I navigate through pages using `NavController`. In some situations, I pass parameters like `this.navCtrl.push('TestPage', { name: 'John' });`. Is there a way to replicate this behavior when using cypress to visit pages like `cy.visit('#/test-page');`?
What I need is the TestPage to recieve the same parameters under cypress testing that it recieves when using the app regularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest cypress version `3.2.0` you could pass parameters in the `cy.visit()` command. Can you try the below to see if the is working for you ?

```
cy.visit('url_goes_here', {
  auth: {
    username: 'some_username',
    password: 'some_password'
  }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I think this approach is aimed for login. For my needs, I need more flexibility on the kind of data I'm sending.